# OnTouchEvent steals from OnClick

Tags: android

I implemented OnTouchEvent ( I need to react on Action.MOVE and Action.Up ) and OnClick, but it never enter in OnClick. OnTouch steals evemt. How to solve this ? I need on touch because Actoion.Up and Action.Move. I have added clickable, focusable and focusableInTouchMode to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want the `TouchListener` to consume events on certain views, you need to make sure that you return `false` for those specific cases in your `onTouchEvent` implementation.  Returning `true` at any point will consume the event and not allow other actions to be performed based on it.

HTH

Comment: However, when returning `false`, the `ACTION_DOWN` won't trigger anymore.  Any way around that?

Comment: `ACTION_DOWN` will always trigger, it's subsequent events that won't come through without a view or listener returning `true`.  You either design the listener to consume events or pass them through...not both.

Answer (score 0):

When you need both click and touch events on the same view, it's best to use a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect).